# Make delete button to delete file at point in dired?

Tags: dired, deletion

In normal file managers like `nautilus`, if i select an item and press <kbd>delete</kbd> button, it will delete that item.

How can i achieve the same in dired? When point is at file, pressing <kbd>delete</kbd> button should delete that item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use library [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then the `delete` key is bound by default to to command `diredp-delete-this-file`, which deletes the file named on the line of the cursor, after confirmation. (`C-k` is bound to the same command.)

This is the entire definition of the command:

```el
(defun diredp-delete-this-file ()       ; Bound to `C-k', `delete'
  "In Dired, delete the file on the cursor line, upon confirmation."
  (interactive) (dired-do-delete 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write a simple function to delete file at point and then bind it to <kbd>delete</kbd> button.

```
(defun delete-current-item ()
  "Delete file at point"
  (interactive)
  (dired-flag-file-deletion 1)
  (dired-do-flagged-delete))

(define-key dired-mode-map  [delete] 'delete-current-item)
```

Comment: You may wish to check out the function `dired-do-delete` attached to the capital letter `D`, which will give a confirmation and then delete the file at point if the user says yes -- no need to flag, etc.